# IText8, error reported when multiple threads write data to the same PDF template

Tags: itext

I have defined a PDF template that defines multiple fields, where the field values come from a certain attribute value of an object, and an object generates a PDF file based on the PDF template. When I have multiple objects, I write PDFs to different objects simultaneously through multithreading, and this will result in an error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current state = RESET, new state = FLUSHED
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.throwIllegalStateException(CharsetEncoder.java:996)
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.flush(CharsetEncoder.java:679)
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:808)
    at com.itextpdf.io.font.cmap.CMapCharsetEncoder.encodeUnicodeCodePoint(CMapCharsetEncoder.java:62)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfType0Font.convertToBytes(PdfType0Font.java:386)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfType0Font.writeText(PdfType0Font.java:414)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas.showText(PdfCanvas.java:826)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas.showText(PdfCanvas.java:708)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TextRenderer.draw(TextRenderer.java:977)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.drawChildren(AbstractRenderer.java:1036)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.draw(AbstractRenderer.java:475)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer.drawChildren(ParagraphRenderer.java:584)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.draw(BlockRenderer.java:564)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.form.renderer.AbstractFormFieldRenderer.drawChildren(AbstractFormFieldRenderer.java:199)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.draw(BlockRenderer.java:564)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.form.renderer.AbstractFormFieldRenderer.draw(AbstractFormFieldRenderer.java:183)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.CanvasRenderer.flushSingleRenderer(CanvasRenderer.java:108)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.processRenderer(RootRenderer.java:370)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.shrinkCurrentAreaAndProcessRenderer(RootRenderer.java:321)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:223)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.CanvasRenderer.addChild(CanvasRenderer.java:72)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.createAndAddRendererSubTree(RootElement.java:346)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.addElement(RootElement.java:355)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(RootElement.java:84)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormAnnotation.drawTextFormFieldAndSaveAppearance(PdfFormAnnotation.java:912)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormAnnotation.regenerateWidget(PdfFormAnnotation.java:1072)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.regenerateField(PdfFormField.java:1097)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.setFieldValue(PdfFormField.java:1426)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.setValue(PdfFormField.java:368)
    at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.setValue(PdfFormField.java:356)
```

I don't know where the problem lies

Comment: PdfDocuments are not thread safe. A solution would be to gather the data on different threads and store it somewhere (class, list,..) and when all threads are completed you Fill the PdfDocument from the gathered data.

Comment: `IllegalStateException - If an encoding operation is already in progress` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode-java.nio.CharBuffer-

Comment: There is no problem with iText5, but upgrading to iText8 will cause this problem.